# use of the enum name

Tags: c++, enums

If someone uses `enum` name as follows:

```
class Logger
{
 public:
           enum LEVEL
           {
               Debug,
               Warning,
               Notification,
               Error
           };
};
```

What would this thing mean here:

```
Logger(LEVEL);
```

Comment: is Logger indeed logger? (or viceversa)

Comment: As Isaac Asimov would say, insufficient data for meaningful answer. For one thing, being that C++ is case sensitive, we don't have a definition for `Logger`. And we don't know what context the call is made in. It could be anything. Static cast from LEVEL to logger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the declaration of a *constructor*, to be used like this:

```
struct Logger
{
    enum LEVEL { Debug, Warning, Notification, Error };
    Logger(LEVEL);
    // ...
};

Logger wlogger(Logger::Warning);
Logger elogger(Logger::Error);
```

Comment: one more thing i need to ask if i define a virtual ~logger();just after the logger(LEVEL);

Answer (score 0):

LEVEL is an enum, It means that LEVEL can only be of values **Debug, Warning,Notification,** or **Error.** `Logger(LEVEL);` is a call to constructor `Logger()` of the class Logger that accepts values only from among **Debug, Warning,Notification,** and **Error** as its first parameter and probably initializes the property `LEVEL` to the value supplied.